# How to adjust Netbeans' "Project Files" filter

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I am working with a NetBeans project with Maven which uses the Maven assemble plugin. That plugin is configured via a file `assemblePlugin.xml` which is in the root folder of the project, just like the `pom.xml`.

But when I look at the project in the *Projects* tree, the folder *Project Files* only shows `pom.xml`, `nbactions.xml` and `nb-configuration.xml`, but not my `assemblePlugin.xml`.

**Edit**: `logging.properties` is another candidate I keep missing.

How can I adjust that filter (or turn it off)?

(Netbeans 8.0.2)